# How to programatically change the login name of an SPUser

Tags: spuser, ldap

I'm facing a problem with Sharepoint as I must change the Login name of my users. I'm in a claim based installation and I decide to use GUID as unique identifier.

By Sharepoint PowerShell I found how to do it and works.. How can I change it programmatically? LoginName properties seems to be read only!

Here's the way I rename it on Powershell:

```
Move-SPUser -Identity $User2 -NewAlias "i:05.t|saml provider|MYBASE65GUID==@DOMAIN.dom" -IgnoreSID
```

Anybody knows a way to do that programmatically in Sharepoint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the login name of an User I used the SPFarm object.

The code looks simple like this:

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
             {
                using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                    foreach (Principal user in ps.FindAll()) //Searches the user in LDAP
                    {
                        if (user.UserPrincipalName == EmailUser)
                        {
                             var BASE64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String((user.Guid.Value).ToByteArray()); //Convert the guid in BASE64
                            SPUser mi = web.EnsureUser("i:05.t|saml provider|"+EmailUser); //get the user I want to change
                            SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local; //get the local farm
                            farm.MigrateUserAccount(mi.LoginName, "i:05.t|saml provider|" + BASE64 + "@fakemail.dom", false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
```

In this way the user has a new LoginName as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

See the [ISPUserMigrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.ispusermigrator_methods.aspx) interface.

Comment: Suggestion on how to use it? I can see no example over there!

Answer (score 0):

Actual code for this Command is under Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell.dll and I used "ILSpy" to see the code under these command. which is this.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.Resources;
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
{
    [Cmdlet("Move", "SPUser", SupportsShouldProcess = true, ConfirmImpact = ConfirmImpact.High)]
    internal sealed class SPCmdletMoveUser : SPCmdlet
    {
        private SPUserPipeBind m_UserPipeBind;

        private SPUser m_User;

        private string m_OldAlias;

        private string m_NewAlias;

        private SwitchParameter m_IgnoreSid;

        [Alias(new string[]
        {
            "UserAlias"
        }), Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, Position = 0), ValidateNotNull]
        public SPUserPipeBind Identity
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_UserPipeBind;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_UserPipeBind = value;
            }
        }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = true), ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
        public string NewAlias
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_NewAlias;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_NewAlias = value;
            }
        }

        [Parameter(Mandatory = false)]
        public SwitchParameter IgnoreSID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_IgnoreSid;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_IgnoreSid = value;
            }
        }

        protected override string ConfirmationMessage
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.m_User == null)
                {
                    return this.m_OldAlias;
                }
                return this.m_User.ToString();
            }
        }

        protected override void InternalValidate()
        {
            if (this.Identity != null)
            {
                this.m_User = this.Identity.Read();
                this.m_OldAlias = ((this.m_User != null) ? this.m_User.LoginName : this.Identity.RawIdentity);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.m_OldAlias))
            {
                base.WriteError(new PSArgumentNullException("Identity", StringResourceManager.GetResourceString("SPUserPipeBindRequired", new object[0])), ErrorCategory.InvalidArgument, null);
                base.SkipProcessCurrentRecord();
            }
        }

        protected override void InternalProcessRecord()
        {
            SPFarm localOrThrow = SPFarm.LocalOrThrow;
            localOrThrow.MigrateUserAccount(this.m_OldAlias, this.NewAlias, !this.IgnoreSID.IsPresent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[SPWeb.EnsureUser(loginName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx)

This will create the user within SharePoint if it doesn't already exist (i.e. the user should be allowed access but hasn't actually visited the site).

Comment: But I want to "rename" an user not to create!

Comment: Ah, I was confused, I thought you were trying to get an SPUser object given a login name. I will edit the title to make it clearer.